# Docker development workflow

Tags: python, django, deployment, docker, workflow

What's the proper development workflow for code that runs in a Docker container?

[Solomon Hykes said](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7724587) that the "official" workflow involves building and running a new Docker image for each Git commit. That makes sense, but what if I want to test a change before committing it to the Git repo?

I can think of two ways to do it:

1. Run the code on a local development server (e.g., the Django development server). Edit a file; test on the dev server; make a Git commit; rebuild the Docker image with the new code; test again on the local Docker container.
2. Don't run a local dev server. Instead, build and run a new Docker image each time I edit a file, and then test the change on local Docker container.

Both approaches are pretty inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient way is to run a new container from the latest image that was built (which then has the latest code).

You could start that container starting a bash shell so that you will be able to edit files from inside the container:

```
docker run -it <some image> bash -l
```

You would then run the application in that container to test the new code.

Another way to alter files in that container is to start it with a volume. The idea is to alter files in a directory on the docker host instead of messing with files from the command line from the container itself:

```
docker run -it -v /home/joe/tmp:/data <some image>
```

Any file that you will put in `/home/joe/tmp` on your docker host will be available under `/data/` in the container. Change `/data` to whatever path is suitable for your case and hack away.

Comment: Thanks! `-v` looks good. But what happens after a change in `/home/joe/tmp` is ready to be committed? Is there an elegant way to copy the code to the Docker image so I can rebuild and deploy it?

Comment: Then commit it and rebuild an image. You should also consider using Jenkins to build those images for you

Comment: But if the code lives on my local dev machine, how do I "commit" it so that it will be included in the Docker image?

Comment: aren't your local dev machine able to commit your files? if not, you're doing something wrong

Comment: I mean that mounting a volume with `-v` doesn't add the code to the Docker image. So when I'm ready to deploy, I'd have to add something like `ADD /home/joe/tmp /data` to the Dockerfile. Then, to go back to developing, I'd have to remove that line, rebuild the image, and run it with `-v`. That sounds like a big hassle.

Comment: You should have a Dockerfile that has either a ADD which put _all_ your source code files into the image anyway. How would it work otherwise to build an image which contains your code? You can then decide to run a container from that image as it is, or with `-v` to overwrite some files. You could also have two different Dockerfiles, one for distributing your app and one for development purpose

Comment: Aha. I didn't realize that `-v` would overwrite the directory created in `ADD`. That's perfect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more note for Mac users: apparently you can only mount a directory with `-v` _from your Mac_ if the directory is located under `/Users` (https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/). If you try to mount something like `/var/tmp/`, it will be mounted _from the Docker host_.